# Mobilefirst 7.1 - What does decommision process does? How to undo decommisioned devices

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

Recently 90 days occured since we went live and the decommision batch was executed which have decommision approzimately 3000 devices. On what bases mobilefirst decomission these devices? Does it completely disables user access? If so how can these devices be enabled again? How to disable the decommision batch process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decommission process marks an inactive device as "Inactive" in the DEVICES table in the runtime database.  A device is considered to be "inactive" if it has not connected to the server in a certain length of time, defined by the "wl.device.decommission.when" JNDI property.  After a further period of inactivity, defined by the "wl.device.archiveDecommissioned.when" JNDI property, an inactive device is removed from the DEVICES table entirely, and placed into an archive file.  The default value of both of these properties is 90 days - so, a device is noted as "Inactive" in the DEVICES table after 90 days of inactivity, and it is removed from the table entirely after a further 90 days of inactivity (unless you have changed the values of these properties to specify different inactivity times).  A device that has been decommissioned would be marked as "Active" again (or put back into the DEVICES table, if it's already been archived) simply by accessing the server again, unless the device access management features are enabled (see details below).  If device access management is enabled, and the inactive device has not yet been archived, the server administrator will need to manually set an inactive device back to "active" in the MobileFirst Operations Console before access is re-enabled.

This is used primarily for license tracking, and to support the device access management features (if you are using them - the ability to disable a device from accessing the server via the MobileFirst Operations Console).  It does not affect whether or not a device can access the server if the device access management features are not being used.  For further information about the relevant JNDI properties and how they are used see the documentation, here:

[License tracking](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/admin/c_license_tracking.html)

and here:

[JNDI environment entries for MobileFirst projects in production](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/r_JNDI_entries_for_production.html)

and here:

[Mobile application management](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_device_mgmt.html)

If you have not licensed the MobileFirst Platform based on number of Client Devices or Addressable Devices (a typical B2C case), and you have no need for the device access management features, you may want to disable device tracking entirely to improve performance, by setting the JNDI property "wl.device.tracking.enabled" to "false".  By default, "wl.device.tracking.enabled" is set to "true", and "wl.device.enableAccessManagement" (which enables the device access management features) is set to "false".